# Iwasawa and Cartan decomposition of $p$-adic classical groups

Tags: lie-groups, p-adic-number-theory, reductive-groups

Let $G:=GL(n)$ be defined over $F:=\mathbb{Q}_p$ (for convenience, of course in general over a $p$-adic field $F$). Then it's well-known that we have the Iwasawa and Cartan decompositions, just as Lie groups:

**Theorem** (1)(Iwasawa decomposition) Let $B$ be the standard Borel subgroup (upper triangular) and $K:=GL(n,\mathbb{Z}_p)$. Then $G(F)=B(F)K=KB(F)$.
(2)(Cartan decomposition) Let $T$ be the subgroup of diagonal elements of $G$. Then $G(F)=KT(F)K$.
(3)(direct corollary of the Cartan decomposition)$K$ is a **maximal** compact open subgroup.

I know the proofs of these facts for $G=GL(n)$ because they are very elementary (linear algebra, row and column reduction of matrices). However, during a course lectured by my advisor to undergraduates (for which I'm a TA, ah ah ah), my advisor left as an exercise to the students to prove the above theorems for $G=Sp(2n)$. Here we let $T$ to be the diagonal subgroup of $G=Sp(2n)$ and $N$ the subgroup generated by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
I_n & 0 \\
S & I_n
\end{pmatrix}\left({ }^t S=S\right), \quad\begin{pmatrix}
u & 0 \\
0 & { }^t u^{-1}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $u\in GL(n)$ is lower triangular. We define the Borel $B$ to be $B=TN$. In this context, we have to prove the above theorem for $G=Sp(2n)$.

I know that these two decompositions hold for $p$-adic classical groups: namely symplectic and special orthogonal groups. I first saw this fact on Bruhat's report in **Algebraic Groups and Discontinuous Subgroups**, Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics 009, AMS, page 66. However, I didn't try to find any reference for this, and for the case $SO(n)$ it requires some Bruhat-Tits theory since in general $SO(n)$ may neither be defined over integers nor split(the proof is more difficult, I think).

Now I have to find an adhoc proof for the case $G=Sp(2n)$ mentioned as above (maybe the onlything I can use is still linear algebra, some special elements in $G=Sp(2n)$?). So far I tried some elements but I can't write down a precise proof. Can anybody help me? And I also want to ask for references on the case $G=SO(n)$. These decompositions are too useful while studying representation theory of $p$-adic groups. Have they been proved for general reductive groups?

Comment: Hey, it's true that the Cartan decomposition holds for any reductive group $\mathcal{G}/\mathbf{Z}_p$ (having a reductive model over $\mathbf{Z}_p$ is what is called *unramified*, and it's true for split groups, but many more (e.g. the unitary group associated to an unramified extension)-- it's actually equivalent to quasi-split and split over an unramified extension). I can in fact tell you something cooler: the Cartan decomposition is EQUIVALENT to reductivity. See this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.00128.pdf

Comment: @AlexYoucis Dear Alex, thanks a lot for your comments and sorry for a late reply. Now I have found an excellent reference: Kaletha and Prasad's new book: Bruhat-Tits Theory, a new approach, chapter 5. Thanks a lot for the "cooler" fact!! This is really interesting. (Since I'm majoring in automorphic representations, I learnt very little algebraic geoemtry. I need to study more AG in order to appreciate the ideas in that preprint.)